# Disabling double submit prevent sending submit name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I run into the bug with my multi form page:

I have two forms:

```
<form>
<input type="submit" id="single-submit" name="form_1" value="Submit 1"/>
</form>

<form>
<input type="submit" id="single-submit" name="form_2" value="Submit 2"/>
</form>
```

And this JavaScript to prevent double submit:

```
$("form").one('submit', function() {
    $('#single-submit').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

I'm trying to get the submit name in php:

```
if(isset($_POST['form_1']))
{
    // form 1 submitted
}

if(isset($_POST['form_2']))
{
    // form 2 submitted
}
```

But JS is preventing this, why?

I can recieve submit `name=""` from second, third... form. But not from the first form on page.

**UPDATE:**

Removed double ids, added classes instead:

```
<form action="example.com/process" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="submit" class="single-submit" name="form_1" value="Submit 1"/>
</form>

<form action="example.com/process" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="submit" class="single-submit" name="form_2" value="Submit 2"/>
</form>
```

And this JavaScript to prevent double submit:

```
$("form").one('submit', function() {
    $('.single-submit').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Moreover now first AND second form does not return submit name.

Also tried `on(` instead, no luck.
So it seems something still wrong with JS.

Without this JS everything is working as expected.

Comment: `$("form").one('submit'`, try using `on(` instead of `one(`.

Comment: typo ?? $("form").one

Comment: You have duplicate `id`, which is illegal html. fix your html, and things will probably start working better.

Comment: Not a typo... `.one` triggers only one time. Google it!

Comment: Removed ids, added classes instead, tried `on(` instead, no luck. But now first AND second form does not return submit `name`

Comment: Please update your question to reflect all of the details.  Comments are not a suitable place to include details or current status of the question.  Since your question is currently closed, the *only* way to get it re-opened (and available for new answers) is to sufficiently describe the question in a way that clearly indicates that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60171869/334451

Answer (score 2):

Use a `class` instead of an `id` on this : `id="single-submit"`.

An `id` must be unique.

Comment: Changed, but problem stayed the same, except now I don't receive submit `name` from neither of two forms.

Comment: Hew... Where do you want it to be "received". Did you set `action` and `method` ? It would look like this : `<form action="some.php" method"post">`.

Comment: Yes, just didn't want to put everything, so it be more clear. As I mentioned, everything is working as expected without this JS chunk that is preventing double click, to be more sure I removed other JS, during the tests.

Comment: You SHOULD edit your question... As the `id` problem isn't the only problem. Your question is now marked as a [duplicate] because of that. If  you edit it... Including all relevant code, it will be re-opened. Hit the "edit" link below your question.